# Passing value as a parameter in Lua

Tags: lua

```
A = {}

function A:text()
    return 100
end

print(A["text"]()) -- prints "100"

----------------------------------

A = {}

function A:text(value)
    return value
end

print(A["text"](100)) -- prints "nil"
```

Is there a way that I can pass a value as a parameter and return the same value?I need to loop through 5 functions...

Comment: Using a debugger, put a breakpoint at the `return value` line, look at the values of the `self` and `value` parameters (local variables) and understand @Nicol's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38531642/2226988).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could, if you declared your function correctly.

```
function A:text(value)
```

This creates a function that takes *two* parameters. The `:` is what's responsible for that. The first parameter is an implicitly declared parameter called `self`. The second is `value`. This function is intended to be called as `A:text(100)` or with `A["text"](A, 100)`.

These are for class-member-like functions.

You should instead create the function like this:

```
function A.text(value)
```

This creates a function that takes one parameter.

Comment: I added "print(A["text"](self, 100))" it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: @S.Jovan: First, you didn't declare `self`, so that code (while legal in Lua) doesn't make sense. Second, your function isn't a method; it doesn't use `self`, so you shouldn't declare it with `:`.

Answer (score 1):

As "Nicol Bolas" pointed out, I add table/self parameter and it worked fine.

```
-- from "A["text"](100)" to "A["text"](self, 100)" or "A["text"](A, 100)"

A = {}
B = {"text", "type"}

function A:text(value)
    return "text "..value
end

function A:type(value)
    return "type "..value
end

for i=1, 3 do
   for j=1, #B do
      print(A[B[j]](self, i)) -- prints "text 1 type 1 text 2 type 2 text 3 type 3"
   end
end
```

Comment: You clearly didn't understand what @Nicolas Bolas tried to explain.

Comment: @user6245072 You clearly didn't understand what I was asking. I wanted to loop through functions and at the same time pass values.

Comment: That's not the point. You are still declaring those function using the `:`, which is unnecessary, and you are now passing an unexistent variable `self` to a function. This works for just a coincidence.